# Adding a variable to String directory path in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

hope someone can help.

I'm trying to create a folder for each user to store there images in using Codeigniter!

I'm have trouble using the username variable in the directory path like so.

```
 class Image extends CI_Controller {

private $data = array(
    'dir' => array( 
            'dir' => array(
                    "original" => "assets/uploads/original/users/".$username."/",
                    "thumb" => "assets/uploads/thumbs/users/".$username."/"
            ),
    'total' => 0,
    'images' => array(),
    'error' => ''
);

function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
}

public function index($start = 0)
{
    $username = "Phil";
    if ($this->input->post('btn_upload')) {
        $this->upload();
    }

    $this->load->library('pagination');

    $c_paginate['base_url'] = site_url('image/index');
    $c_paginate['per_page'] = '5';
    $finish = $start + $c_paginate['per_page'];

    if (is_dir($this->data['dir']['thumb']))
    {
        $i = 0;
        if ($dh = opendir($this->data['dir']['thumb'])) {
            while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
                // get file extension
                $ext = strrev(strstr(strrev($file), ".", TRUE));
                if ($ext == 'jpg' || $ext == 'jpeg' || $ext == 'png') {
                    if ($start <= $this->data['total'] && $this->data['total'] < $finish) {
                        $this->data['images'][$i]['thumb'] = $file;
                        $this->data['images'][$i]['original'] = str_replace('thumb_', '', $file);
                        $i++;
                    }
                    $this->data['total']++;
                }
            }
            closedir($dh);
        }
    }

    $c_paginate['total_rows'] = $this->data['total'];

    $this->pagination->initialize($c_paginate);

    $this->load->view('images/index', $this->data);
}

private function upload()
{
    $c_upload['upload_path']    = $this->data['dir']['original'];
    $c_upload['allowed_types']  = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg|x-png';
    $c_upload['max_size']       = '100';
    $c_upload['max_width']      = '1024';
    $c_upload['max_height']     = '768';
    $c_upload['remove_spaces']  = TRUE;

    $this->load->library('upload', $c_upload);

    if ($this->upload->do_upload()) {

        $img = $this->upload->data();

        // create thumbnail
        $new_image = $this->data['dir']['thumb'].'thumb_'.$img['file_name'];

        $c_img_lib = array(
            'image_library'     => 'gd2',
            'source_image'      => $img['full_path'],
            'maintain_ratio'    => TRUE,
            'width'             => 100,
            'height'            => 100,
            'new_image'         => $new_image
        );

        $this->load->library('image_lib', $c_img_lib);
        $this->image_lib->resize();
    } else {
        $this->data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
    }
}

public function delete($ori_img)
{
    unlink($this->data['dir']['original'].$ori_img);
    unlink($this->data['dir']['thumb'].'thumb_'.$ori_img);
    redirect('/image');
}
```

}

/* End of file image.php */
/* Location: ./system/application/controllers/image.php */

Comment: where is `$username` from ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning private value and use another variables in it.
You should use something like this :

```
class Image extends CI_Controller {

private $data = array();

function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
}

private function assignUsername($username)
{
    $this->data = array(
        'dir' => array( 
            'dir' => array(
                "original" => "assets/uploads/original/users/".$username."/",
                "thumb" => "assets/uploads/thumbs/users/".$username."/"
            ),
        'total' => 0,
        'images' => array(),
        'error' => ''
    );
}

public function index($start = 0)
{
    $username = "Phil";
    $this->assignUsername($username);

//rest of file
```

Comment: That code is no different from my original post, you get an error at the  first .    as I have shown in my very first post in this topic.

Comment: Have added it to the original post, the error is at the first .

Comment: Thank you Paul worked a treat much appreciated for your time!

Answer (score 0):

seems nothing wrong there but you can Use Double Quotes instead

```
'dir' => array( 
        'original' => "assets/uploads/original/users/$username/",  
        'thumb' => "assets/uploads/thumbs/users/$username/"
    ),
```

Comment: The variable $username will output as string $username in your answer, I need it to be a variable $username.

Comment: I get the output-----Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/codeigniter/application/controllers/image.php on line 8 using the above answer

Comment: Because syntax seems fine to me even the "username" variable is empty it will be only "//" in execution or the warning.

Comment: see this.[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Comment: Thank you for the link but I'm getting the same!-------------Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"' in /code/KxQJhS on line 6
PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"' in /code/KxQJhS on line 6